# Add xcframework as Swift Package dependency with SSH

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework

When i try to add my xcframework as a swift package dependency through ssh URL, Xcode give me error

```
Showing All Messages
x-swift-package-repository-authentication://?scm=com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git&url=git@ghe.somegiturl.git#error=-1005 Authentication failed because the credentials were missing
```

I can clone this repo through same ssh URL through source tree, it works fine. Package.manifest file below

```
let package = Package(
name: "Test",
platforms: [
         .iOS(.v12)
    ],
products: [
    // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
    .library(
        name: "Test",
        targets: ["Test"]),
],
dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
],
targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .binaryTarget(
                name: "Test",
                path: "Test.xcframework"
            ),
    .testTarget(
        name: "TestTests",
        dependencies: ["Test"]),
]
```

)

Comment: Xcode SPM tool only supports ssh keys generated with RSA algorithm. Generate your SSH key with RSA algorithm, and this issue will not hamper your work.